# How to specify default arguments in a Service or Action

Tags: actionlib

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is it possible to define default arguments in a Service or Action message? I want to expose several options in services and actions, but it seems by default, ROS makes all fields required. How do you specify defaults?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/233567/how-to-specify-default-arguments-in-a-service-or-action/) by [Cerin](https://answers.ros.org/users/2186/cerin/) on ROS Answers with karma: 940 on 2016-05-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The ROS message, service and action formats do not allow you to specify defaults for any of the fields.

It may be better to expose several services, or you may want to write a C++ or python wrapper class around the service or actionlib client that provides the defaults.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2016-05-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0